# How to calculate the position of an element from its atomic number?

Tags: periodic-table

How to calculate the place of of a element if know their atomic number in a periodic table?

Comment: Try writing the electronic configuration of that element. It will give you some clues.

Answer (score 1):

You will not fail following the numbers of periodicity from one electron in the outer electronic shell to the completely filled shells. Shells are filled

- in the first shell with **2** electrons ($\ce{_2He}$),
- in the second shell with **8** more electrons ($\ce{_10Ne}$)
- in the third shell with again **8** more electrons ($\ce{_18Ar}$)
- in the fourth shell with **18** more electrons ($\ce{_36Kr}$)
- in the fifth shell with again **18** more electrons ($\ce{_54Xe}$)
- in the sixth shell with **32** more electrons ($\ce{_86Rn}$)
- in the seventh shell with - you guess - again **32** electrons.

The positions of elements were arranged empirical by their chemical properties by [Mendeleev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmitri_Mendeleev) in 1865. Years later it became clear that atoms consist of electrons, arranged around the nucleus and the mentioned above electron configurations are inert or [Noble gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas).

Unfortunately physics claims shells to have [$2n^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration#Shells_and_subshells) electrons (where $n$ is the number of the shell). Which brings you to the point to learn about [Aufbau principle and Madelung rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration#Atoms:_Aufbau_principle_and_Madelung_rule).

Comment: Well, physics is perfectly correct, as long as you consider a shell to be represented by a single principal quantum number $n$. Nobody said that shells must correspond exactly to rows in the Periodic Table, which is what you seem to be talking about.